# django model property not showing up in object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

so i have the mentioned model down here which I created a property for , for some reason my properties started to NOT show up in my objects

```
class Cars(models.Model):

datetime = models.DateTimeField()
source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
color = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
year_built = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
submission = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
sell_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
chassis = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
engine = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=200)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
insurance_left = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
body = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
gearbox = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
mileage = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
price = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
model_year = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
car = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
car_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
img = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True,blank=True)
company = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)


@property
def letstestproperty(self):
    return 'hello world'




class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Car Records'
```

I output my objects using

```
Cars.objects.values()
```

but there are no property field added to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal behavior of the Django ORM is to return fields on `values()` It does not include property as they are not fields that map database rows fields(column names). However, if you want all fields then just call `all()` or `first()`

```
Cars.objects.all() or .first()
```

`all()` is used to get all objects of the model and `first()` is used to get the first object from all of the objects of the model at DB level.

Comment: I still not return the property value